# Where is the fault in my proof?

Tags: proof-verification

I had some spare time, so I was just doing random equations, then accidentally came up with a proof that showed that i was -1. I know this is wrong, but I can't find where I went wrong. Could someone point out where a mathematical error was made?

$$(-1)^{2.5}=-1\\
(-1)^{5/2}=-1\\
(\sqrt{-1})^5=-1\\
i^5=-1\\
i=-1$$

Comment: The first line?

Comment: @amcalde So -1^2.5 doesn't equal -1?

Comment: As a rule, once you have negative or complex $x$, it is no longer true that $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$.

Comment: A little confusing.  The -1 should be in parentheses (otherwise the power only applies to the 1, but judging by the third line, you want the power to apply to (-1).

Comment: Why do you merely assert that $(-1)^{5/2}$ is $-1$?

Comment: @RK01 Nope.  See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(2.5)

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that because I put in -1^2.5 into my calculator without putting the parentheses around the -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have "$(-1)^{5/2} = -1$". It actually holds that $(-1)^{5/2} = i$ since you get by euler identity that 
$$(-1)^{5/2} = {e^{i\pi}}^{5/2} = e^{5/2 i\pi} = i.$$ 
Furthermore you shouldn't write $\sqrt{-1} = i$ because the root isn't defined for negative values and you can get all sorts of wrong proofs by using the rules for square roots in combination with this notation.

Answer (score -1):

$$(-1)^{2.5} =(-1)^2\times (-1)^{1/2}= \sqrt{(-1)} =  i$$ is your mistake

Comment: Sorry, that line is nowhere in the OPs argument, so it can't be the OPs mistake.

Comment: user352874 is asserting that $(-1)^{2.5}$ **is** equal to i, not -1 as RK01 said.  The OP's mistake was in **not** saying that.  Of course, user 352874 is  also mistaken,  $(-1)^{2.5}$ is multivalued.